# How does JAXB map a class name to an XML element name?

Tags: java, jaxb

I am using JAXB (the version included with JDK 6) to marshall objects to XML. The following piece of code yields unexpected results:

```
    public class JAXBTest {
        @XmlRootElement
        public static class VIPPerson {}
```

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        VIPPerson p = new VIPPerson();
        JAXB.marshal(p, sw);
        System.out.println(sw.toString());
    }
}
```

The output from the above is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<vipPerson/>
```

I am expecting to see the class name mapped to the `VIPPerson` element rather than `vipPerson` based on section 8.12.1 in the [JAXB specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr222/index2.html), which says

> class name: a class name is mapped to an XML name by de capitalization using java.beans.Introspector.decapitalize(class name ).

The JavaDoc for that `decapitalize` method says this:

> Utility method to take a string and convert it to normal Java variable name capitalization. This normally means converting the first character from upper case to lower case, **but in the (unusual) special case when there is more than one character and both the first and second characters are upper case, we leave it alone**.
>   Thus "FooBah" becomes "fooBah" and "X" becomes "x", but "URL" stays as "URL".

Does the implementation violate the spec or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is caused by a [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6505643) in the reference implementation. Looks like it won't be fixed due to the compatibility problems it would cause. The workaround is to explicitly specify a name with `@XmlRootElement`.